# Phase angle greater than 2pi and and less than -2pi is there meaning

Tags: matlab, theory, fft, quaternions

I can do an fft of a voice/audio signal and get the different phases, intensity's, and frequencies accurately.  What I'm trying to understand is why do certain values for the phase angle become greater than 2pi or less than -2pi?  I know I can do a modulo of the phase angle so it doesn't go past 2pi or -2pi but I'm trying to understand why I can get a phase angle of -1343 radians or 234 radians and if there is another meaning to having such large phase angles.

An Example would be quaternions which deals with higher dimensional math do we arbitrarily ignore something by not taking into account such large negative and positive phase angle values?

Comment: How are you determining that the phase is that big?  The Matlab `angle` function should give you a result in the range +/-pi.

Comment: Without posting the whole code here's the part your asking about
I was more interested in the reason why the values could be so high and if they held another meaning.  But the code works well I've even rebuilt the signal using the values and did an absolute error check and it checks out.
nfft= 2^(nextpow2(length(vp_sig_orig))); 
 fftx = fft(vp_sig_orig,nfft); 
 NumUniquePts = ceil((nfft+1)/2); 
 fftx = fftx(1:NumUniquePts);
phase = unwrap(angle(fftx));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwrapped phase angles of an FT spectrum are useful if you are trying to plot or analyse a continuous phase change over time (frequency modulation, etc.) or over frequency (multi-pole filter response, phase vocoder or cepstrum/cepstral analysis or synthesis), without jump discontinuities over time, frequency or quefrency, which could ruin linear operations, plot slope regression, and etc.

Answer (score 2):

@hotpaw's answer is a good one.  Another situation where large phase angles can arise is in a phase-locked loop (PLL).  A PLL tracks phase error (i.e. the integral of frequency error), and tries to make it zero.  A phase lag greater than 2pi means that the synthesised oscillator needs to catch by more than a whole cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the example with quaternions, it's possible that you do some quaternion algebraic operation (with the meaning being *composition of rotations*) and get out a value for the rotation angle that's outside the range `[-2 * pi , 2 * pi]`.  But this doesn't break the math and you don't get any problems from this.  Just map the angle back to the desired range when you want to interpret it.

However, this example is significantly different from the FFT phase of a voice signal example.